# Differentiation under the integral sign for Lebesgue integrable derivative

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, leibniz-integral-rule

The problem is the following:

> Let $a,b,c,d \in \mathbb R$ be given such that $a<b$ and $c<d$. Suppose $f : [a,b] \times [c,d] \to \mathbb R$ is a function such that $\partial_1 f: [a,b] \times [c,d] \to \mathbb R$ exists and is (Lebesgue-)integrable.
> Show that for $t\in [a,b]$ we have
> $$\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt}\int_c^d f(t,x) \, \mathrm dx = \int_c^d \partial_1 f(t,x)\, \mathrm dx$$

---

I have tried the following: By the fundamental theorem of calculus, we have

$$f(t',x) - f(t,x) = \int_{t}^{t'} \partial_1f(s,x)\, \mathrm ds$$

It follows that

$$
\begin{align}
\int_c^d f(t',x)-f(t,x) \, \mathrm dx &= \int_c^d \int_{t}^{t'} \partial_1f(s,x)\, \mathrm ds \, \mathrm dx \\
&= \int_{t}^{t'} \int_c^d \partial_1f(s,x)\, \mathrm dx \, \mathrm ds
\end{align}
$$

so that *for almost all* $t$, we have

$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt}\int_c^d f(t,x) \, \mathrm dx 
&= \lim_{t'\to t} \frac{1}{t'-t}\int_c^d f(t',x)-f(t,x) \, \mathrm dx \\
&= \lim_{t'\to t} \frac{1}{t'-t}\int_{t}^{t'} \int_c^d \partial_1f(s,x)\, \mathrm dx \, \mathrm ds \\
&= \int_c^d \partial_1f(t,x)\, \mathrm dx
\end{align}
$$

since $t \mapsto \int_c^d \partial_1f(t,x)\, \mathrm dx$ is an $L^1$ function (hence almost every point $t$ is a Lebesgue-point).

Unfortunately equality for almost every $t$ is not good enough in this case.

I have been thinking about this for quite a while now, but I cannot figure out the reason for why every point $t\in [a,b]$ has to be a Lebesgue point of

$$t\mapsto \int_c^d \partial_1f(t,x)\, \mathrm dx$$

I have also been thinking about possible counterexamples, but couldn't really come up with one. (At least not if one defines $\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt} \infty = 0$ for the constant function $\infty$...)

Some help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need $\partial_1f(t,x)$ be dominated by an integrable function, i.e., you need $|\partial_1f(t,x)|\le g(x)$ for every $x,t$ for you to take the limit $t'\to t$ inside the integral for every $t$.

Just $\partial_1f(t,x)$ being integrable over $[c,d]$ for every fixed $t\in [a,b]$ isn't sufficient.

Edit:

Let me clarify things here. The problem is that you can not straightaway write $$\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt}\int_c^d f(t,x) \, \mathrm dx 
= \lim_{t'\to t} \frac{1}{t'-t}\int_c^d f(t',x)-f(t,x) \, \mathrm dx $$ unless you have already shown that $\int_c^d f(t,x) \, \mathrm dx$ is differentiable w.r.to $t$.

So, let $t_n$ be a sequence converging to $t$ and let $$g_n(x)=\frac{f(t_n,x)-f(t,x)}{t_n-t}$$ Then $\lim g_n(x)=\partial_1 f(t,x)$ (given).

Then by mean value theorem $$|g_n(x)|\le \sup_{t\in [a,b]}|\partial_1 f(t,x)|\le g(x)$$ so DCT applies to $g_n(x)$.

Therefore $$\lim_{t_n\to t} \frac{1}{t_n-t}\int_c^d [f(t_n,x)-f(t,x)]\mathrm dx$$ exists and is equal to $$ \int_c^d \lim_{t_n\to t}\frac{f(t_n,x)-f(t,x)}{t_n-t}\mathrm dx=\int_c^d \partial_1f(t,x) \, \mathrm dx$$

I have just reproduced here what I once learnt from Folland's Real Analysis book.

Comment: O.k., now I understand what you are saying. And I agree that the additional assumption of $\partial_1f(t,x)$ being uniformly bounded in $t$ by some $g(x) \in L^1[c,d]$ would be sufficient. Nevertheless, what I have written is true - as I stated - *for almost all* $t$. If you could provide a counterexample to prove: "Just ∂1f(t,x) being integrable over [c,d] for every fixed t∈[a,b] isn't sufficient."  then that would be great!

Comment: How can one write $\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt}\int_c^d f(t,x) \, \mathrm dx= \lim_{t'\to t} \frac{1}{t'-t}\int_c^d f(t',x)-f(t,x) \, \mathrm dx$ before knowing whether the limit exists.

Comment: It's existence is justified for almost all $t$ by the next line after that and the fact that $$t\to \int_c^d \partial_1f(t,x) \, dx$$ is an $L^1$ function (so almost every $t$ is a [Lebesgue-point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_point) ).

Comment: ah I see. Good point.

Comment: If we only have that the derivative is integrable, do we have an a.e t result? attainable only as a weak derivative?

Answer (score 4):

I have found a non-trivial counterexample:

Let $I = [0,1]$. I will construct a counterexample $f \in L^1(I\times I)$. Showing that additional assumptions along the lines of

- For every $t_0\in I$ there exists $g\in L^1(I)$ and a neighbourhood $U$ of $t_0$, s.t. for all $t\in U$ we have: 
  $$|\partial_1f(t,x)| \le g(x) \qquad\text{almost everywhere}$$

cannot be dispensed with (if we want the claimed equality to hold for all $t$ rather than almost all $t$).

We define $f: I\times I\to \mathbb R_{\ge 0}$ by

$$f(t,x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \chi_{I_n}(x) \beta_n(t)$$

where

- $I_n = (2^{-n}, 2^{-n+1})$ and $\chi_{I_n}$ denotes the characteristic function of $I_n$,
- $\beta_n:I \to \mathbb R$ is differentiable with

  - $0\le \beta_n(t) \le \dfrac{2^n}{n(n+1)}$, $0\le \beta_n'(t)$ for all $t\in I$,
  - $\beta_n(t) = \begin{cases} 0 & 0\le t \le \dfrac{1}{2n} \\
    \dfrac{2^n}{n(n+1)} & \dfrac 1n \le t \le 1 \end{cases}$

i.e. every $\beta_n$ is a monotonic differentiable function which is constant near $t=0$.

For a fixed $x$ at most one summand in the definition of $f(t,x)$ is not equal to zero, so there are no problems with convergence.

Thus we obtain $\partial_1f(t,x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \chi_{I_n}(x) \beta_n'(t)$ and - using nonnegativity of all summands

$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^1\int_0^1 |\partial_1f(t,x)|\, dt\, dx 
&=  \int_0^1\int_0^1 \left(\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \chi_{I_n}(x)\beta_n'(t)\right) \, dt\, dx\\
&= \sum_{n=1}^\infty |I_n| (\beta_n(1) - \beta_n(0)) \\
&= \sum_{n=1}^\infty 2^{-n} \frac{2^n}{n(n+1)} \\
&= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\frac1n - \frac1{n+1}\right) \\
&= 1 < \infty
\end{align}
$$
Similarly a quick calculation shows
$$
\int_0^1\int_0^1 |f(t,x)|\, dt\, dx \le 1 < \infty
$$
Therefore $f, \partial_1f \in L^1(I\times I)$. But now we observe
$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^1 \frac{f(1/m, x)-f(0,x)}{1/m} \, dx 
&= m \int_0^1 \left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty \chi_{I_n}(x)[\beta_n(1/m) - \beta_n(0)]\right)\, dx \\
&= m\sum_{n=1}^\infty |I_n|\beta_n(1/m) \\
&\ge m \sum_{n=m}^\infty 2^{-n} \frac{2^n}{n(n+1)} \\
&= m\cdot \frac{1}{m} = 1
\end{align}
$$
for all $m\in \mathbb N$. In particular, with $\partial_1f(0,x) = \sum_n \chi_{I_n}(x) \underbrace{\beta_n'(0)}_{=0\; \forall n} = 0$ we see:

$$\limsup_{t\to 0} \int_0^1 \frac{f(t, x)-f(0,x)}{t} \, dx \ge 1 \ne 0 = \int_0^1 \partial_1f(0,x) \, dx$$

Showing that $f$ is a counterexample as claimed.