# Justifying the differentiation under the integral of density of a Brownian motion

Tags: derivatives, brownian-motion, density-function

I have a relatively simple question but I don't know how to do it. Let $p(t,x) := \frac{1}{\sqrt t} e^{-\frac{x^2}{2t}}$, $t>0, x\in \mathbb R$. I would like to justify

$$ \frac{\partial}{\partial t}\int_\mathbb{R} p(t,x)dx = \int_\mathbb{R} \frac{\partial}{\partial t} p(t,x)dx.$$

using the standard differentiation theorem. However, I cannot find an integrable function $g(x)$ such that

$$|\frac{\partial}{\partial t}p(t,x)| = \Big|-\left(\frac{x^2}{2t^2\sqrt t} +\frac{1}{2t\sqrt t} \right) e^{-\frac{x^2}{2t}}\Big| \leq g(x), \quad \forall t>0 \quad  \text{and} \quad a.e \quad x. $$

Any help for this case is highly appreciated. If possible, I would like a general statement for $p(t,x) = e^{\frac{-|x|^2}{2t}}$, $t>0$, $x \in \mathbb R^n$ as well. Thank you very much!

Comment: This question needs some motivation. $\int p(t,x)\,dx = \sqrt{2\pi}$ for all $t>0$.

Comment: The conditions for swapping derivative and integral is a common question: for example check this wikipedia link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule

Seems like a similar question was also asked before: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2530213/when-can-we-interchange-integration-and-differentiation

Comment: You do **NOT** need a uniform bound over all $t>0$. Differentiability is a local property, so all you need to do is for each $t_0>0$, find some interval $I$ around $t_0$ such that the supremum over all $t\in I$ is an integrable function of $x$. I’ve commented on a similar issue [Interchanging spatial Fourier transform and time derivative for heat kernel](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4434893/568204).

Comment: @AlanChung the link doesn’t answer OP’s question. They already seem to know the general measure-theoretic theorem for differentiation under the integral sign. It’s just a matter of applying the theorem correctly, by recognizing the local nature of differentiability.

Comment: @peek-a-boo That's quite exactly what I want, thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

It is well-known that
$$\tag{1}
\int_{\mathbb R}p(t,x)\,dx=\sqrt{2\pi}
$$
for all $t>0\,.$ The time derivative is therefore zero. The fact
$$\tag{2}\boxed{\quad\phantom{\Big|}
\int_{\mathbb R}\partial_t\,p(t,x)\,dx=0\,.\quad}
$$
can be shown directly without seeking an integrable function $g(x)$ that majorizes
$|\partial_t\,p(t,x)|\,:$

In slight contrast to you I get
$$\tag{3}
\partial_t\,p(t,x)=\frac{p(t,x)(x^2-t)}{2t^2\sqrt{t}}\,.
$$
Clearly,
\begin{align}
\int_{\mathbb R}\partial_t\,p(t,x)\,dx&=\frac{1}{2t^2\sqrt{t}}\underbrace{\int_{\mathbb R}x^2p(t,x)\,dx}_{\sqrt{2\pi} t}-
\frac{\sqrt{2\pi} t}{2t^2\sqrt{t}}=0\,.\tag{4}
\end{align}
because the  variance of a normal random variable with density $p(t,x)/\sqrt{2\pi}$ is  $t\,.$
$$\tag*{$\Box$}
\quad
$$